# Replaced screen in Acer Aspire, now won't power on or acknowledge it's plugged in

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, acer-aspire

I recently replaced the LCD screen from a different model Acer Aspire (Both 15.6" , same connector and LED backlight) in my laptop. I've replaced LCDs from other laptops before, so I'm fairly competent in doing these repairs:

Donor PC:
Aspire 5750 Series
Model No: PSWE0
5750-6425
(This laptop will actually still power on, but immediately turns off, bought it for parts)

Transplanted PC (One that received the new screen)
Aspire 5733
Model No: PEW71
5733-6696

I powered on the laptop for a test after placing the screen in it, I *think* I seen a spark come from the connector to the screen. The laptop still powered on, but the screen was black, I had to hold in the power button to shut it off. I removed the connector to the back of the screen and try powering it on again... nothing. I did this all on carpet, I hope I didn't build up static and destroy the motherboard?

I put the battery back in and tried to start it again, nothing.

It's basically dead to the world right now. Not acknowledging a charge or anything. Holding in the power button does nothing. I noticed the side with the power jack gets warm on the bottom, not sure if that means anything. ***EDIT: It's the heatsink that gets warm, right on top of the processor***

Since this is a Q&A website:

-What did I do wrong? I realize tearing apart a laptop on carpet isn't exactly genius but I've done it before with no issues.

-What tests can I do now to isolate the problem? I tried removing the video cable right from the motherboard, still nothing though.

Comment: I think you answered your own question: worked on carpet, discharged spark, now laptop is taking the big dirt nap. Just becuase nothing happend before with carpet and sparks does not mean it will never happen. Just my two cents.

Comment: If so, I'm going to have to look at this as a lesson. Luckily I have another computer that this screen will fit...

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being the motherboard. As an earlier comment stated, static electricity and electronics is a bad combo.